# Fetch image file from Backendless in swift

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I have imported my Parse db to Backendless and I'm seeing that my image content is in relation with data in string format, so when I try to fetch it shows only as string(URL).How can I call or convert url to UIImage.Thank you

See script below :

```
func fetching() {

    let backendless = Backendless()
    let query = BackendlessDataQuery()

    backendless.persistenceService.of(Menu.ofClass()).find(query, response: { ( menu : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in

        let currentPage = menu.getCurrentPage()

        print("Loaded \(currentPage.count) Menu objects")

        for menu in currentPage as! [Menu] {
            print("Menu name = \(menu.name)")
            self.name.text = menu.name
            self.type.text = menu.type
            print("Type = \(menu.type)")
            print(menu.image)
        }
    },
    error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in

        print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    })
}
```

Comment: show an example of the string, presumably you need to download the file it points to (i don't expect it to be a base64 encoded version of the image)

Comment: URL : https://api.backendless.com/XXXXXXXX/v1/files/import/F9207F9D-FBC9-BC3D-FF29-0B95F385E2003757f-pickles.png

Comment: Use NSURLSession to get the image.

Comment: thanks @ryantxr...it works like charm :)

Comment: How did you achieve it using NSURLSession?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image file, in a similar manner to how you used to download the PFFile. It's generally a good idea to use a library like `SDWebImage` to manage the download and caching of the image for you.

Comment: Well I don't think is a good idea to download image (when you have approximately 100 photos)...btw I have figured out by calling as url.